# Google Map not getting displayed on web page

Tags: html, google-maps

Am trying to put a Google map on my webpage ,but the following code is not working for me

where am i going wrong,please rectify this

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=
"https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu/@19.1040931,72.8403963,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3be7c9bf5aae1367:0xd0b948b462f60df5?hl=en">
</iframe>
<br />
<small>View <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/Tns6b"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.co.in/maps?t=m&amp;q=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu,+Mumbai,+Mumbai+Suburban,+Maharashtra&amp;z=14&amp;ll=19.104093,72.840396&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://www.google.co.in/maps?t=m&amp;q=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu,+Mumbai,+Mumbai+Suburban,+Maharashtra&amp;z=14&amp;ll=19.104093,72.840396&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

You did'nt close a tag (small)  and some minor fix.Hope this would work now